# Hover box with (vertically and horizontal) centered text

Tags: css, position

I made a on-hover-information-box for an image-mosaic for a client. When the person hovers the image (different orientations, so its flexible sized) he gets another `div` above it with some informations. The flexibility is the problem: I want the content of the `div` vertically and horizontal centered. At the moment it looks like this:

```
.linkbox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
}
```

But I want to the stuff to appear in the middle of the box. So my first thought: `padding-top:40%;` and a height of (maybe!?) 50% and the rest for the Information. I know I have to make the size in % too but thats just gross. Do you have any idea?

The project is here: http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/archive/

Comment: Did you try [vertical-align:middle](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)?

Comment: Do you need this to work in IE7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a look at this : **Link** http://jsfiddle.net/qfXVa/2/

```
div.linkbox {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.linkbox div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I basically set a container for the text content and aligned it Vertically and Horizontally middle to the parent.

Comment: Hey, I tried this one but I don't think it works with me because I don't have a fixed size for the outer box (it has to be flexible for the orientations of the images). Any solutions? I wrote it down in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qaENL/

Answer (score 1):

This is the best guide I have found to vertically centering/aligning content:

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

From the guide, you could use the following CSS:

```
<span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle">Your content</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center text in middle of a `div` I found the following works best:

```
.center
{
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can also use:

```
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Well, that's just centering it horizontally - he wants it to be vertical aswell.

Comment: I did this with "text-align:center" because its just text there. But I need to get this "flexible height but vertical centered"-problem fixed!

Comment: @ninetwozero, Quite right. Updated.

Comment: Bear in mind margin: auto will only work in most browsers if a specific width and height are set.

Comment: @Julius Koroll, try the above and you should be something like what you want with these.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the methods described in [this blog post](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/).

I would try `vertical-align:middle` or go for this solution:

```
<div id="top">
<h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<div id="floater"></div>
<div id="content">
Content Here        
</div>

#floater    {float:left; height:50%; margin-bottom:-120px;}
#top    {float:right; width:100%; text-align:center;}</strong>
#content    {clear:both; height:240px; position:relative;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me --

HTML :

```
<a style="display: block;" class="fancybox linkbox-709 linkbox" href="http://www.davidgoltz.de/2011/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/black-forest.jpg">
<div id="wrapperC" style="display: table; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div id="cell" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class="content">
            <span class="datum">Aug 8th</span>
            <h1 class="post-title-archive">Black Forest</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapperC {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapperC {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in your css, second declaration should be for `.cell`.